# Does Gcross theo-value assume both marked point patterns as randomly distributed?

Tags: r, spatial, spatstat

So I have been diving into **spatstat** lately and found a wonderful function called **Gcross**. I want to use it to test the distribution of two marked point patterns for complete spatial randomness.

Background: I have cells with x- and y-coordinates in a tissue section and want to see if they show colocalization, beyond the amount of colocalization you would get by randomness, e.g. show that cells of two phenotypes are more likely to colocalize.

For a reproducible example I took the dataset *anemones* and I created two different Gcross functions, for different *i*'s (need to turn the numeric marks into factors first):

```
anemones$marks <- as.factor(anemones$marks)
G3 <- Gcross(anemones, i="3",j="2")
G4 <- Gcross(anemones, i="4",j="2")
```

My problem: the theo value for G3 and G4 is exactly the same, regardless of the density of *i*.
Theo is defined in [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spatstat/versions/1.64-1/topics/Gcross) as

> the theoretical value of Gij(r) for a marked Poisson process with the same estimated intensity

As far as I have understood, theo should be calculated for the assumption that both *i* and *j* are randomly distributed (a Poisson distribution), so I would expect different results for the theo value.

Any idea where my code or my understanding of the function is off?

Answer (score 2):

The theoretical value of `Gij(r)` depends on the estimated intensity of the points of type `j` only. (The formula for the theoretical value is given in the help file for `Gcross`.)

In your example, the two functions `G3` and `G4` are calculated for different `i` but for the same `j`, so the theoretical values are the same in each function.

In a nutshell, `Gij(r)` is the probability that, for a given point of type `i`, there is at least one point of type `j` within a distance `r`. If the points of different types are independent, then this is the same as the probability of finding any points of type `j` within a distance `r` of any fixed location, which clearly depends only on the characteristics of the points of type `j`.

For more information, see Chapter 8 of [the spatstat book](https://book.spatstat.org).

Comment: Thanks alot! Do you have any idea whether theres a function or an easy way to simulate that both are randomly distributed?

Comment: Strongly suggest you read Chapter 8 of the spatstat book. You can use the functions Gcross and Jcross to answer different kinds of questions. Use rpoispp, rmpoispp to generate completely random patterns. Use rlabel or rshift to randomly perturb an existing point pattern. The chapter has explanations and examples.